# Multilingual Site in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, multilingual, zend-translate

i am working on a site to include Multilingual Support.
I can translate strings using Zend_Translate but what about the content??
For example do i have to add multiple records for same product's for each language? Or is there any other way?
I am new to multilingual please help.
Thanks in advance.

--- Addition -----------------------------

Ok, i decided to use a mixed solution to use google translation api and storing it in database for further editing. So what sould be the structure of database to store translations???

1. Should i save translations of different language in same table as parent record. i.e. for product in product table with an extra column to identity language.
2. A generalized single table to store all translations of all tables. e.g. translations (id bigint,table_name vc(50),table_id bigint, langugae, column_name vc(50), translation )

should i save records in related tables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Few possible approaches:

1. Using `gettext` (or software like [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)) to extract the data from the content. Possible with variable interpolation.
2. Creating view filter like described in: [Zend Framework and Translation](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4513)
3. Have separate content of the data in the database.
   If you store the content in markup (e.g. [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)) format, anyone can translate it easily. It's easy to create search engine in different languages.

Seems the third approach requires the most efforts, but it is worth.

#### Update after comment

I assume you store your product data in the database, in fields like:

```
- product_data
-- id
-- price
-- name
-- description
-- etc…
```

So you should modify it, to add fields for translated strings in each language:

```
- product_data
-- id
-- price

- product_data_translations
-- product_id
-- language (e.g. en)
-- name
-- description
-- etc
```

Then you can easily build SQL queries to extract translated data `where product_id=x and language="fr"`.

You may use also [Doctrine I18N](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/behaviors/hu#core-behaviors%3ai18n) to do it for you automatically.

You need to translate the content manually (or automate the translation using Google API), but then, you can easily index it using for example [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html).

Comment: It shouldn't be gettext OR Poedit, it should be gettext AND Poedit. Poedit is just a gettext client, you will still need gettext to get the text ;-).

Comment: @tharkun Right, but I ment just command line `gettext`, not the technology called *gettext™*

Comment: +1 @takeshin thanks bro for your response but i did not get your third point fully, please can you explain.

Comment: @takeshin, But i hope i could find something new, i will probably accept your answer after getting some more responses.