# Multilingual website issues

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual

I have to maintain a website in three languages: Arabic, English, and Pashto.

When the users select a language, for example arabic, when he applies any search in my website, how that search will be applied in my database?

When I'm updating the website (of course in english), how those updates will be reflected for arabic and pashto languages in the database?

Comment: What wud he search for? What info you keep in DB? depends on all. Not a prefered method thogh i can say smthng like use an intermediate translator. like A MODEM :P

Comment: My eyes. I need punctuation. ^_^

Comment: All of your questions depends on how your site is built. You will have to give us some more information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store multiple languages in an XML file (you can use http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php to find what language you want based on the user`s selection), maybe even caching it...my opinion

Pro: further development (more languages)

Answer (score 1):

1. First you have to decide what would be you database approach. [Multilingual Site in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057386/multilingual-site-in-zend-framework)
2. Secondly you have to decide what would be the approach to translated from one language to another. There are some options regrading this.

   3. Add translated text for each language manually.
   4. Use some translating service like google translate. But i dont think that you can rely on that. You have to add some approval system for translated text.